# capistrano: cp - cannot stat

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano, sprockets, errbit

I'm trying to deploy errbit (https://github.com/errbit/errbit), and can't get capistrano to compile the assets on a remote server.
It appears it's adding for no good reason some gibberish when it creates the manifest path, and I really have no idea where to watch to fix it...

Here is the Capistrano output

```
  01 /usr/local/rvm/bin/rvm 2.3.0 do bundle exec rake assets:precompile
  01 Notice: no rspec tasks available in this environment
  01 Overwriting existing field _id in class App.
  01 Creating scope :page. Overwriting existing method NotificationServices…
✔ 01 deployer@000.000.000.000 2.336s
  00:22 deploy:assets:backup_manifest
  01 mkdir -p /home/deployer/apps/errbit/releases/20160426123255/assets_man…
  01
✔ 01 deployer@000.000.000.000 0.330s /home/deployer/apps/errbit/releases/20160…
  02
  02 cp: cannot stat ‘\033[?25h\033[0G\033[K\033[?25h\033[0G\033[K/home...
  02 : No such file or directory
  (Backtrace restricted to imported tasks)
  cap aborted!
  SSHKit::Runner::ExecuteError: Exception while executing as deployer@000.000.000.000: cp exit status: 1
  cp: cannot stat ‘\033[?25h\033[0G\033[K\033[?25h\033[0G\033[K/home/deployer/apps/errbit/releases/20160426123255/public/assets/.sprockets-manifest-cd1becb3ebe39b1efd086cd82910b5dd.json’: No such file or directory
  cp stderr: Nothing written

  SSHKit::Command::Failed: cp exit status: 1
  cp: cannot stat ‘\033[?25h\033[0G\033[K\033[?25h\033[0G\033[K/home/deployer/apps/errbit/releases/20160426123255/public/assets/.sprockets-manifest-cd1becb3ebe39b1efd086cd82910b5dd.json’: No such file or directory
  cp stderr: Nothing written

  Tasks: TOP => deploy:assets:backup_manifest
  (See full trace by running task with --trace)
  The deploy has failed with an error: Exception while executing as deployer@000.000.000.000: cp exit status: 1
  cp: cannot stat ‘\033[?25h\033[0G\033[K\033[?25h\033[0G\033[K/home/deployer/apps/errbit/releases/20160426123255/public/assets/.sprockets-manifest-cd1becb3ebe39b1efd086cd82910b5dd.json’: No such file or directory
  cp stderr: Nothing written
```

As you can see before /home/deployer there are some randomcharacters I'm not able to understand.

The only place I think could have something to do is the deploy_to instruction:

```
set :deploy_to, '/home/deployer/apps/errbit'
```

Here is my Gemfile.lock

```
https://gist.github.com/ngw/1157a005ff7f6077b9f5b232b0371a76
```

I'm not able to see the problem here.

Can someone help me?

Comment: Do you use something like [`nvm`](https://github.com/creationix/nvm) , could you show the content of the home folder `~/` with hidden files?

Comment: `‘\033[?25h\033[0G\033[K\033[?25h\033[0G\033[K` is bash control  codes, have you used colors in env vars?

Comment: I'm using rvm, the only files I added are .ruby-version and .ruby-gemset that appear to work pretty well. Their content are "2.3.0" and the name of the gemset.

Comment: @МалъСкрылевъ maybe, i assume it is all about bash login, looks like the remote shell try to do something and fail with error redirection.  I have the same issue it was  be the node version manager and the `.nvmrc` file.

Comment: make sure the directory `/home/deployer/apps/errbit` exists on the server you are deploying to

Answer (score 0):

fixed for me:
`bundle update capistrano`
in deploy.rb change
`set :pty, true`
to
`set :pty, false`